# Actionscript - randomly drop from moving plane MC

Tags: random, actionscript, positioning

I wasn't quite sure how to describe my problem in the subject. I have a plane MC and a crate MC. The plane only flies along the y axis from the bottom of the screen to top. Along the way I want it to randomly drop the crate MC. My code is below. The problem is that the crates spontaneously keep spawning and not near the plane.

```
function movePlane():void
{
    var tempY:Number;
    var tempX:Number;
    var tempCrate:MovieClip;
    var tempPlane:MovieClip;

    for (var j:int =planes.length-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        tempPlane = planes[j];
        tempPlane.y +=  tempPlane.planeSpeed;
        tempCrate = new Crate();
        tempY = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempPlane.y);
        tempX = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempPlane.x);
    }
    tempCrate.y = tempY;
    tempCrate.x = tempX;

    addChild(tempCrate);
}
```

Comment: So you want a crate to be created for each plane in your list of planes as it moves? Or do you want to create ONE crate which appears n the same position on a randomly chosen plane?

Comment: one create for each plane as it moves.

Comment: So if we say planes[1] will move from 0 to 100 in y. Do you want the crate the appear randomly between 0 and 100?

Comment: No. The plane flies from bottom of screen to the top of the screen. so somewhere between the top and bottom of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

To make a crate drop on each plane once you can create this behavior by creating a timer on each plane with a random time value. Like this:

```
function addRandomCreation():void{
    var animationTime:Number = 5000; //The time the planes will be animating in ms 

    for(var i:int = 0; i < planes.length; i++){
        var planeTimer:Timer = new Timer(Math.round(animationTime * Math.random()));
        planeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerComplete(i));
        planeTimer.start();
    }
}

function timerComplete(planeID:int):function{
    return function(event:TimerEvent):void{
        event.target.stop();
        event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);

        var tempCrate:MovieClip = new Crate();
        tempY = Math.round(Math.random() * planes[planeID].y);
        tempCrate.y = tempY;
        tempCrate.x = planes[planeID].x;
        addChild(tempCrate);        
    }
}
```

**Edited answer:**

This will create a crate on the same x axis as the plane it's being created by.

```
function movePlane():void
{
    var tempY:Number;
    var tempX:Number;
    var tempCrate:MovieClip;
    var tempPlane:MovieClip;

    for (var j:int =planes.length-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        tempPlane = planes[j];
        tempPlane.y +=  tempPlane.planeSpeed;
        tempCrate = new Crate();
        tempY = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempPlane.y);
        tempCrate.y = tempY;
        tempCrate.x = tempPlane.x;
        addChild(tempCrate);
    }
}
```

You have have to use addChild each time you create a new Crate otherwise it will just create a lot of crates which only the last one will be added to the stage. To do this you have to move the addChild into the loop.

```
function movePlane():void
{
    var tempY:Number;
    var tempX:Number;
    var tempCrate:MovieClip;
    var tempPlane:MovieClip;

    for (var j:int =planes.length-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        tempPlane = planes[j];
        tempPlane.y +=  tempPlane.planeSpeed;
        tempCrate = new Crate();
        tempY = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempPlane.y);
        tempX = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempPlane.x);
        tempCrate.y = tempY;
        tempCrate.x = tempX;
        addChild(tempCrate);
    }
}
```

Comment: No go. The crates continually spawn randomly all over the screen.

Comment: You have to give me a better explanation. You say you want to create a crate each time a plane move for each plane. Then that's your solution. Or do you want the crate to be created randomly on y axis but on the same x axis on the plane it's created by?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining better. Yes I want the crate to be created randomly on y axis but on the same x axis on the plane it's created by

Comment: Alright, then have a look at my edited answer. It works by taking the x positon by the current plane in the loop and using that for the crate.

Comment: That works better as the crate is now lined p properly on the x axis, however it adds many crates along the y axis as the plane moves. I just need to make it so that only one crate per plane is dropped.